# change integrals by fubini's theorem

Tags: calculus

can we use fubini here :
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$ $$= $$ 
$$\int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} dtdx$$
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the integrand $$\frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p x^{p-1}}$$ is nonnegative, you can use Fubini-Tonelli's theorem. But you did a mistake. If you want to integrate on the region $$\left\{(x,t)\,\middle|\,0\leq x \leq \tfrac{1}{t},\ 1\leq t\leq\infty\right\}$$ by changing the order of $x$ and $t$, you must observe that the above region is same as $$\left\{(x,t)\,\middle|\,1\leq t \leq \tfrac{1}{x},\ 0 \leq x \leq 1\right\}.$$ Then, the theorem tells us that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{1}^{1/x}\frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} dtdx$$

Comment: thanks butt i think mor precisly that the equality in the exercice is
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p}dtdx$$ $$ =$$ $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$$$+$$ $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$

Comment: this is what the exercice says but for me the question of region is clear i think ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, only i found in the last integral that it is equal to 
$$\int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} dtdx$$   i don t know if i am right :)
and for that i ask if the last integral and mine are equal so if we can use fubini because here The symbol t is a dummy integration variable and cannot appear as an integration limit of the outer integral

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your iterated integral using dummy variable....

Comment: but what do you think about this 
The region $$0<t<1/x $$ for$$ x∈[0,1]$$is the union of the regions $$[0,1]×[0,1] $$ and$$ 0<x<1/t $$ for $$ t>1$$